# Rails 3.1 SSL redirect loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, jboss, jruby

As usual, I'm having strange issues with deploying a Rails app to our different staging environments.  I have configured my Rails 3.1 app to use SSL config.force_ssl = true.  When I warble the project the war deploys correctly to our test JBoss server (4.2.2), and is accessible over https.  When I move to production, the app is not accessible giving the following messages.

**UPDATE**
Ok, after deploying again I have a little more information.  The site is currently hosted on https://ibs.collegegreen.net/Campus-Commerce when the page is hit, I receive a redirect loop error that eventually resolves to https://ibs.collegegreen.net/Campus-Commerce//////////////////////

In addition, we have an Apache server that proxies the requests back to our JBoss servers.

```
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp//] miss
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp///] miss
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp////] miss
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp/////] miss
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp//////] miss
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp///////] miss
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp////////] miss
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp/////////] miss
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp//////////] miss
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp///////////] miss
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] cache: [GET /MyApp////////////] miss
```

**production.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.js_compressor = :closure

  # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
  #config.assets.manifest = Rails.root.join("config")

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  #config.assets.precompile += [ '*.js', 'cc/*.js', '*.css', 'skins/*.css', 'smoothness/*.css' ]
  config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )

  # Enable threaded mode
  config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the issue, it was with Apache.  We found the following link relevant to adjusting Apache http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=995